# Player tag does not respond to AddForce

Tags: unity, collision-detection, physics

I have a player with rigidbody and it has a tag as *Player* .

[image]

I have set a sphere collider as *trigger* with script

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Addforce : MonoBehaviour {

```
public int speed;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up*speed);
    }
}
```

}

I have set speed force to 100.

But when player enters the collider, nothing happens. It doesn't tag it.

Comment: Please post the script code as code and not as a screenshot.

Comment: I see you have a Rigidbody First Person Controller script attached. It's possible that this is overriding the physics inputs from other sources. Can you share some details of this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the sphere is a trigger, you need to use `OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)` instead of `OnCollisionEnter`.

`OnCollisionEnter`, `OnCollisionExit` and `OnCollisionStay` are called when both objects' colliders are not triggers.

Moreover, you should specify that the force added is an impulse. You should do this:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Addforce : MonoBehaviour {

    public int speed;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up*speed, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't apply force on player if I change OnTriggerEnter.

Comment: Yes, addforce  script is attached to green cuboid with sphere collider as trigger.

Comment: Galandil, now it does work . But I had to uncheck IsTrigger on sphere collider.

How to add an angle to the force? About 45 degrees.

Comment: @Wildfire why you had to uncheck `isTrigger`? `OnTriggerEnter` would never fire if both objects are not a trigger.

Comment: Otherwise, it does not work if I check IsTrigger on sphere collider. Player just walks on the collider.

Comment: If I use OnTriggerEnter, Unity gives me error message : Script error: OnTriggerEnter
This message parameter has to be of type: Collider

Comment: Ooops sorry, I just typed outside of VS and used the wrong type, I corrected the code.

Comment: Now it does work. Thank  you. What was the issue ?
Do you know how to add angle to the force so that Vector3.up is replaced by some angle vector ?

Comment: "Adding an angle" is too generic: angle relative to what? Anyway, you should not ask additional questions in the comments, you should try to do it yourself, and if still stuck open another question detailing your problem, what you want to achieve and what have you tried so far. ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74786/discussion-between-wildfire-and-galandil).